# Hundreds of JBoss 5.1 System Threads WAITING forever

Tags: java, threadpool, jboss5.x

About 3 months ago we migrated to JBoss 5.1.0.GA and a few days after testing we found several Out Of Memory Errors (OOME) in the logs of our app.

Then [I found an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBVFS-159) that described the cause as a bug in the JVM up to version 7. We updated to version 7u25 and we haven't seen more OOME but now I see an abnormally huge thread count: about 2k threads and of them 1.9k are daemon threads.

After checking in our monitoring tools I discovered that they are all threads generated by the JBoss system thread pool (they are all named JBoss System Threads(1)-XXXX). And here is the Stack Trace Details:

```
"JBoss System Threads(1)-1649" Id=130217 in WAITING on lock=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@a4d1d3
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have also checked in the tool for collection leaks and found the next data that I think is somewhat related:

[image: Collection Leak Info]

I have checked JBoss JIRA but haven't found something related.

Can someone point me what is going on?

UPDATE:

Here is the thread pool configuration in the jboss-service.xml

```
<!-- A Thread pool service -->
   <mbean code="org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicThreadPool"
      name="jboss.system:service=ThreadPool">
      <attribute name="Name">JBoss System Threads</attribute>
      <attribute name="ThreadGroupName">System Threads</attribute>
      <!-- How long a thread will live without any tasks in MS -->
      <attribute name="KeepAliveTime">60000</attribute>
      <!-- The max number of threads in the pool -->
      <attribute name="MaximumPoolSize">3200</attribute>
      <!-- The max number of tasks before the queue is full -->
      <attribute name="MaximumQueueSize">3200</attribute>
      <!-- The behavior of the pool when a task is added and the queue is full.
      abort - a RuntimeException is thrown
      run - the calling thread executes the task
      wait - the calling thread blocks until the queue has room
      discard - the task is silently discarded without being run
      discardOldest - check to see if a task is about to complete and enque
         the new task if possible, else run the task in the calling thread
      -->
      <attribute name="BlockingMode">run</attribute>
   </mbean>
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the collection. it's just that you have a large collection of threads. what are your threads doing and why aren't they terminating?

Comment: I believe you just have a misconfigured thread pool. Once the app experiences high load, it starts all those threads and never terminates them. You must limit the core pool size and the timeouts. My application had the exact same problems and I believe the admins were able to solve it through configuration.

Comment: @happymeal for the stacktrace I think they are just waiting for work

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I updated the question with the thread pool configuration.

Comment: Even though it doesn't explain why all of them hang on, 3200 threads is clearly overkill :-) You could fix at least that.

Comment: Our devop said that it was OK, so let's believe him. But I cannot find why they hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads were created by the pool as the version of Java that ran the server was incompatible. We switched to an earlier version and the problem was gone.